# Idempotent `beginning-of-defun`

Tags: navigation

How to obtain/implement a `beginning-of-defun` drop-in replacement that is idempotent?

i.e., if I already am at the beginning of a defun, `beginning-of-defun` should do nothing, rather than jumping to the beginning of the *previous* defun.

I acknowledge though that the following case would be ambiguous:

```
(defun ...)

| ;; <------ cursor is here. What should the function do: jump to next or previous defun?

(defun ...)
```

Comment: Can't you just invoke `end-of-defun` before calling `beginning-of-defun` to get the behavior you describe?

Comment: Fantastic, that will do.